# Check to see if a field is within an array in twig

Tags: loop

Hi I am looking for a way to check to see if a field has content within an array of fields. If any of the fields have content I want text to display, but only once so I can't just use a for loop.

The below solution works but there must be a better way to do this?

```
{% set foo = 0 %}
{% for field_group in item if field_group.sticky_nav|length %}
    {% set foo = 1 %}
{% endfor %}

{% if foo >= 1 %}
    <p>Text</p>
{% endif %}
```

Item looks something like this

```
[item] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] =>
                [description] =>
                [link] =>
                [sticky_nav] => foo
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] =>
                [description] =>
                [image] =>
                [sticky_nav] => bar
            )
    )
```

I'm really looking for a solution like the following which doesn't work.

```
{% if field_group.sticky_nav in item %}
    <p>Text</p>
{% endif %}
```

Does anyone know of a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: **no**. According to what Twig is capable of doing, your loop is optimized as is.

The better way of doing it is to check the values with a php loop and then sending the flag to Twig.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If that's the case I'll just leave it as is. It's a once off snippet so I'm not going to worry about it further.